# How to call a double method from a class so it can be used in multiple classes in C#?

Tags: c#

So I have the method that makes the factorial of a number but I don't want to make it every time I need it. I want to make it global so I can call it everytime I need it.

```
double factorial(int i) 
{
    int input = i;
    double result = 1;

    if (i == 0)
    {
        result = 1;
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        while (input != 1)
        {
            result = result * input;
            input  = input - 1;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

What is does is that if gives you the factorial of a number in my Windows Form but I use it in all my windows forms so I copy this method in each class.

```
p = factorial(i))
```

That's how I call it and it works perfectly but is there a way to make it it's own class so I don't have to copy it to every one of my windows Forms and if so how would I call it?

Answer (score 4):

> I copy this method in each class. Is there a way to make it it's own class?

Absolutely! Since your method does not depend on fields of your class, make it `static`, and add it to a class that hosts math helper methods, for example

```
public static class MathHelpers {
    public static double Factorial(int i) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that I also marked the class `static` to ensure its users that they never need to create an instance of it. Essentially, such class becomes a holder of `static` methods.

You call the method from your form as follows:

```
double f = MathHelpers.Factorial(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can add this to a class and make the method `public static`.